# textview with button in gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm new in android.I dont't understand how to add textview with button that changes with respective selected image.Can anyone help me through the proper code.How could i do this?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Add textview with button? What does that mean? Please make what you're looking for a bit more clear so we can address your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of your response, setup either a collection, or an arraylist to hold your objects, and then reference them based on what you've clicked.

Here's how you would do this with a single image, if the image was the only object in the activity.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_RESOURCE"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text for the picture"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
ImageView photoImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

photoImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
    void onClick(View v){
        text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});

// Set the OnClickListener for "button" here, to start a new intent or whatever
```

If you're using multiple buttons, setup an arraylist or collection like I stated above.

**[EDIT]**

Your code to put something into an array list looks like the following...

```
List<TextView> tvs = new ArrayList<TextView>();
// Setup the views
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTextViews; i++){
    TextView thisTextView = new TextView(context);
    // Setup whatever layout info you want here
    tvs.add(thisTextView);
}
// Use a view inflater here to add each of the textviews however you want (table layout, linearlayout, etc.)
```

You can then do whatever you want based on that... just use the `tvs.get(NUMBER)` to snag whatever it is you're looking for. You can do the same thing with your buttons or whatever else, and use the same NUMBER to reference your strings, textviews, and buttons all at the same time. E.g., click on button number 1... you can use `tvs.get(1)`, `buttons.get(1)`, `stringResources.get(1)`

Does that make more sense?